# how to select users from a particular table in mysql and display them in html div ordered list using php

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I want to use PHP and AJAX or jQuery to populate the chat area (id `messages`) with all the members in a database. When a user clicks on any member, all messages sent by the member should be displayed in a different `<div>`.
I am a beginner in PHP and AJAX but I want to get this working. [This is a similar example. I am only interested in how to get it done, not the styling.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvGyI.png)

I have created 2 tables in my database. The `members` table contains `member_id`, `email`, and `name`. The `member_details` table contains `messages`, `time`, and `source`.

```
<div class="header_sec" id="getdata">
    <!-- print member list -->
</div>
<div class="chat_area" id="messages">
    <!-- print information -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // $("#getdata").click(function(){
    function dis(){
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "select.php", false);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
        document.getElementById("getdata").innerHTML =  xmlhttp.responseText;
    }

    dis();

    setInterval(function(){
        dis();
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

This is my PHP script.

```
<?php
echo '<link href="main_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />';

$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");
mysqli_select_db($link, "eazattend");
$res = mysqli_query($link, "select * from members");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    echo '<strong class="primary-font">'.$row['name'].'</strong>';
    if($row['email' != '']){
        echo '<span class="badge pull-right" style=" background-color: green;">'.$row['city'].'</span>';
    }
    echo "<hr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Was that list really necessary? Thanks to that list, it's unclear what you're asking...

Comment: Ok as i said i am a beginner so dont really know alot. Please what will be the best option? Thanks

Comment: @Zeke i think i need to be clear. I have edited my question for you have a better understanding of what i really mean. Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: Thank you for editing the question, now it's a lot more clear. I will add some edits too so I can better help you. I think I get the idea and you'll have to be patient because you'll need some key concepts. Still, not impossible. I just hope it doesn't get too long.

Comment: Waiting patiently my senior programmer. Very much appreciated.

Comment: You deleted my edit... also, don't call me that. You know, just limit your HTML to what is actually needed. Don't copy everything. Where will the member list be output? In what division shall the information appear once the member was clicked? Please edit your PHP using proper indentation, it's a mess as it is. And remember that all I can help you with thus far is how to send the request and manage the response, but getting the actual information will be your duty.

Comment: Well noted...please forgive me.Please i want the member list to be ouput in the div with id = getdata. The information should be appear in the chat area div.

Comment: Please is my editing ok? Pardon me if its very bad because i am new to the world of programming. Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not, I just edited it again, please check it out and accept it. Just don't delete it this time. I'll create an answer and post it, that should get it to work. If we encounter issues, we will solve them in the comments/updates. But someone might do it before me anyway.

Comment: Alright...doing that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before actually copying and pasting the code I wrote here, note that I deleted stuff from the PHP that you don't need at the place where they were.

> I deleted the PHP part where the stylesheet `<link>` tag was echoed because that should be done within the `<head>` tags. I deleted the connection to MySQL and the database selection because that should be done at the very top of the page. **Don't forget to write these where they should be.**

I wrote it in PHP and AJAX, using the [Fetch API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) for the AJAX part. Therefore I added 2 JavaScript functions that are needed for this to work: `status` and `text`. These are explained in the link.

Remember, **I am not adding the PHP code needed to get the HTML for the chat area.** That depends on how you actually want to write it. But as long as you make **a PHP file that *only* echoes out what's needed in the chat area**, then you'll be fine. I already set up AJAX to print all that into `<div class="chat_area" id="messages"></div>`.

You can also handle errors in the catch section where I commented `// handle errors`. You can use JavaScript there to let messages appear or whatever you wish.

### HTML/PHP

```
<div class="header_sec" id="getdata">
    <?php
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `members`");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
            echo '<div onclick="dis('.$row['member_id'].')">
                <strong class="primary-font">'.$row['name'].'</strong>';
            if(trim($row['email']) != ''){
                echo '<span class="badge pull-right" style="background-color: green;">('.$row['email'].')</span>';
            }
            echo '</div>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<div>There are no members.</div>';
    }
    ?>
</div>
<div class="chat_area" id="messages"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="current_member_id" value="0">
```

### JavaScript

Pay special attention to the comments.

```
<script type="application/javascript">
    function status(response){
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300){
            return Promise.resolve(response);
        } else {
            return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText));
        }
    }

    function text(response){
        return response.text();
    }

    function dis(id){
        if(id === '' || id === null || id === undefined){
            id = document.getElementById('current_member_id').value;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('current_member_id').value = id;
        }
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('id', id); // add member ID to send with the request
        // the default value is 0, so "select.php" should check for a member_id that is different than 0
        // if the sent value is 0, then nothing should be returned, or an message for empty results, or similar.
        fetch('select.php', {
            credentials: 'include',
            body: data,
            method: 'POST'
        }).then(status).then(text).then(function(response){
            document.getElementById('messages').innerHTML = response; // receives HTML to be output in the chat area
        }).catch(function(error){
            // handle errors
            console.error(error);
        });
    }

    dis();

    setInterval(function(){
        dis();
    }, 2000);
</script>
```

I hope this is enough, let me know if something doesn't work.

Comment: Will give you appropriate feedback. Thanks alot

Comment: But before that @Zeke i wanted my js script to poll every 2 seconds to check whether there's an update on the mysql database and add to my member list and messages. I can't find that in your codes. Thanks for you quick response.

Comment: Because I commented it out. Read the last part, it's just commented. The problem is that you need to pass the ID as a parameter, so if you wish to do that, then you have to store the current ID in a hidden `<input>` and use that as the parameter. Let me add it to my answer.

Comment: Alright...waiting patiently.

Comment: I updated the answer. Please pay attention to the comments I added. Read it all. There are a few things to keep in mind, especially in the requested PHP file.

Comment: Alright..well noted. Thanks

Comment: By the way, in the HTML/PHP side, I only added one line at the end, but it's **crucial**.

Comment: Have seen that please

Comment: Hey, I just edited something. I added an `else` in the JavaScript. Please check it out, because it's important too!

Comment: Alright have done that

Comment: Hi Zeke, i get some output of which i dont really know  what's happening because i have checked the opening and closing tags. The output is:      0){ while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ echo '
'.$row['name'].''; if(trim($row['email']) != ''){ echo '('.$row['email'].')'; } echo '
'; } } else { echo '
There are no members.
' } ?>

Comment: Did you use the PHP part in `select.php`?? **You must not do that.** That file is on your own to write. I did not touch it. And I'm not planning to do so, since that is part of your very own project and has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Please pardon me for how i sent the output..I am new to this environment. Promise to pick up soon.

Comment: Yes i did use it. Ok please let me debug and get to you. Thanks

Comment: Hi i have...got this output: The output is: 0){ while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){ echo ' '.$row['name'].''; if(trim($row['email']) != ''){ echo '('.$row['email'].')'; } echo ' '; } } else { echo ' There are no members. ' } ?>                                                                                                                                     Jeffery nm@me.com                                                                                                   
 eleonora me@you.com

Comment: Ok sure... just to hint you something, you have to do something similar, but use the `member_details` or `messages` table, I don't know how you managed that to be honest. And create the file using 100% PHP, echoing the HTML. And **only** echo out the chat area. There really is nothing else to do there, that's why it's called chat area. In other words, you're **not** supposed to echo out an entire new page.

Comment: Oooook...get you now. Programming is for great minds indeed...lol

Comment: Wait, you're mixing things up... don't change the code that I gave you, I can see there that you changed it all. Be careful, if you delete the `<div>` where the `onclick` attribute is placed, then this will never work. Don't edit my code, just use it and try it. And I received your message, please answer there.

Comment: Alright i will please

Comment: Perfect...it worked like magic. Very much grateful Zeke.